# An error occured trying to enumerate the contents of folder ''. FTP Passive mode is not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ftp, amazon-ec2, iis-8

I'm trying to publish my mvc project to amazon ec2 t1.micro instance using ftp. It is using iis 8. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-the-ftp-service/adding-ftp-publishing-to-a-web-site-in-iis-7#01).

I'm having this error:

> An error occured trying to enumerate the contents of folder ''. FTP Passive mode is not >available

Anyone know what is the problem?

Thanks in advance,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Seems that FTP server on your Amazon instance doesn't have passive mode enabled. Please re-check this.